# Class instantiation syntax

Tags: c++, constructor, instantiation, standards, parentheses

I've always been taught that

```
1. Class c(arg);
```

and

```
2. Class c = arg;
```

are two totally equivalent statements, but look at this situation.

```
#include <iostream>

class Intermediary {
};

class Left {
  public:
    Left(const Intermediary &) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }   
};

class Right {
  public:
    // The argument is there just so that the example can work, see below
    Right(int) { 
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << std::endl;
    }

    operator Intermediary () const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << std::endl;

        return Intermediary();    
    }
};
```

Now if I do this:

```
Left l = Right(0);
```

The compiler will complain

```
error: conversion from Right to non-scalar type Left requested
```

But if I do this:

```
Left l(Right(0));
```

Then everything compiles and the output is

```
Right::Right(int)
Right::operator Intermediary() const
Left::Left(const Intermediary&)
```

However, if I do this:

```
Left l = (Intermediary)Right(0);
```

then everything compiles again and the output is just like the one above.

So obviously

```
1. Class c(arg);
```

and

```
2. Class c = arg;
```

are not the same, but why not, and what's the difference? I couldn't find anything about this online.

Comment: The answer is that you were taught wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've always been taught that `Class c(arg);` and `Class c = arg;` are two totally equivalent statements, but look at this situation.

It turns out they are not equivalent. The first one constructs the `Class c` out of an `arg`, while the second one constructs a `Class` out of an `arg` and then copy-constructs `Class c` out of it. Note that the implementation is allowed to ellide that copy, and it usually does.

```
Left l = Right(0);
```

This requires a conversion from `Right` to `Intermediary`, and one from `Intermediary` to `Left`. This two sequential user defined conversions are not allowed by the standard, you have to do at least one of them explicit as you do with:

```
Left l = (Intermediary)Right(0);
```

Comment: +1: Right, and just to re-state for clarity, the (1) syntax doesn't have this problem as there is only the conversion from `Right` to `Intermediary`.

Comment: Ok, I had thought that much, but as said I couldn't find anything about it online, and I also tried implementing a copy constructor for class `Left`, compiled with -O0 just in case the compiler would elide it, but still I've had no signs of it being invoked.

Now I wonder: why does the standard mandate that those are not equivalent statements? Is there any technical reason for why it has to be so?